# How to pass table values from one servlet to another servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am retrieving results from SPARQ Query and displaying it on a table. Now When I click on a table row, I should get a the details in another page. How should I do that? My current servlet is `ServletComparison`. The servlet which needs to display details is `CandidateDetails`

```
while(rs.hasNext())
        {
            QuerySolution sol = rs.nextSolution();
            RDFNode object = sol.get("label");
            RDFNode object2 = sol.get("label2");
            RDFNode object3 = sol.get("label3");
            RDFNode object4 = sol.get("label4");

            str += "<tr><td> "+ object +" </td>" +
                    "<td> "+ object2 +" </td>" +
                    "<td> "+ object3 +" </td>" +
                    "<td> "+ object4 +" </td>" +
                    "<td> <form action=\"CandidateDetails\" 
                           method=\"get\">\n" +
                    "       <input type=\"submit\" value = \"Details\">\n" +
                    "     </form> </td> " +
                    "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: For a start I suggest that you move to a MVC paradigm where the servlet is for getting the data and jsp (using EL) is used for displaying the data.  In the above code, it unclear what you are wanting to do especially as you are saying `method=get` but you are using a `submit` button which will do a POST.  You are going to wanted to use the ID of the `RDFNode` to be passed as part of your queryString (GET) to `CandidateDetails`  - this is very basic part of a web application.  You may want to cosider using a FRameWork such as Strust, Spring MVC or Stripes

Comment: Yah. That is exactly what I need to do. I need to get the value in object and send it as a parameter to the next servlet page. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: Use session variebles.